# Let $x$ be a whole number. Show that $x(x-1)(x+1)$ divided by $6$ is a whole number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

Proving things in mathematics is very difficult for me. I don't quite understand what to do here:

Let $x$ be a whole number
Show that $x(x-1)(x+1)$ divided by 6 is a whole number

I really appreciate any help

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is show that $x(x+1)(x-1)$ is always a multiple of $6$. This is the same as showing that it is always a multiple of $2$ and it is always a multiple of $3$. Try what happens a few values of $x$ - can you see a pattern that tells you why $x(x+1)(x-1)$ is a multiple of $2$ in each case? What about $3$?

Comment: I do see the pattern now, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Note that $x-1,x,x+1$ are three consecutive numbers. Hence at least one of them is even (is a multiple of 2) and exactly one of them is multiple of 3. Hence their product is a multiple of 6.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did'nt see that, but now it very clear

Answer (score 0):

This question tests your understanding of the integers modulo 6, also called $\mathbb{Z}_6$

You need to show that
$$
x(x-1)(x+1)=0~ (mod ~6)
$$
If $x=0$, $x=1$, or $x=5$, it’s true.  If $x=2$ or $x=3$, we also have a multiple of 6, so it’s also true.  Likewise if $x=4$, we have a multiple of 12, so it’s also true.